# reshaping an letter in an equation

Tags: math-mode, equations

I need to put a letter under the min symbol in the equation below but i couldn't do it,It now looks like this:

[image]

and I need it to look like this:
[image]

```
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
mina\sum^{N}_{i=1}\sum^{N}_{j=1}|y_i - y_j|^2 W_{ij}
\label{eqn4}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\min_A\sum^{N}_{i=1}\sum^{N}_{j=1}|y_i - y_j|^2 W_{ij}
\label{eqn4}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

To add to Przemysław Scherwent's answer, in the case you want to use an operator that is not already defined, you can use `\operatorname{}` or `\operatorname*{}` from the `amsmath` package.
The former displays its argument like an operator -- like `sin`, for example --, and the latter does the same, but the following superscripts and subscripts will be typeset above and below -- juste like `min`.
If you want to use a custom operator often, you might also want to use `\DeclareMathOperator` or `\DeclareMathOperator*`.

For instance, say you want to use the operator `foo` with subscripts typeset under it. The following code produces the same equation twice :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{foo}
\begin{document}
    \[
        \foo_A
    \]
    \[
        \operatorname*{foo}_A
    \]
\end{document}
```

The nice thing about these is that it handles the spacing around the operators pretty well.